# How do I create a plain-text version of an HTML email?

Tags: spam, newsletter, spam-prevention

We are doing EDMs and we're doing it manually. However, this time, we only have 1 big image and some text at the bottom for the EDM (the image is like a christmas card). It goes directly to spam but there is no reason for us to add more text at the bottom. One way I've read is to add a "text-only" version.

But how?

Are there other ways to lower the spam score?

Answer (score 0):

You have not said how you are creating your email, that will have a bearing on any answers you might get re inserting a text only email.  You could load your image to a website and have a text only email with a URL link to it. How you do that depends on your authoring tool.

WRT lowering your spam score, have a look at http://www.mailingcheck.com this is a free service to let you test the spam scores of your email